# Is it possible to extend a Type that could be Null?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a type I would like to extend, however my only reference to it has it defined as

`type Foo = TypeIamInterestedIn | null`

This is with `strictNullChecks` on.

Here is a [tsPlayground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Test1%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%0D%0Atype%20Test2%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20string%20%7D%20%7C%20null%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ExtendedTest1%20extends%20Test1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ExtendedTest2%20extends%20Test2%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20type%20error%20an%20interface%20may%20only%20extend%20a%20class%20or%20another%20interface%0D%0A%20%20%20%20date%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D) example:

```
type Test1 = { name: string }
type Test2 = { name: string } | null

interface ExtendedTest1 extends Test1 {
    date: number
}

interface ExtendedTest2 extends Test2 { // type error an interface may only extend a class or another interface
    date: number
}
```

Is there anyway to just select the non-null type to extend here?

Comment: I see no error in the referred playground...

Comment: options => `strcitNullChecks` it doesn't seem to get saved with the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Exclude` to get `null` out of there. `Exclude` is a conditional type that will remove the second type parameter from the first type parameter. In this case we can remove the `null` type from the union type.

```
type Test2 = { name: string } | null

interface ExtendedTest2 extends Exclude<Test2, null> { 
    date: number
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, excludes has a lot of potential Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You might even want to just define `type NotNull<T> = Exclude<T, null>`

Comment: @IngoBürk yeah that could be useful, also more clear when reading